J1 Internship Tax Years
I'll do an internship in the US for PhD students on a J1 visa. The internship starts in October 2024 and ends in mid-January 2025.
As I understand, I must file a tax return since I earned income in the US. However, I've realised that my internship is over two tax years. Does this mean I must file two tax returns?
Thanks in advance.
Manuel

Yes, you will file a tax return for each year. Your employer will probably have some assistance program to help you with that. You might also need to do some tax reporting in your home country.
